# tinymce using bbcode with Accented Characters

Tags: tinymce, bbcode

I use tinyMCE with some ajax functions. I have my own button to save content, when the user presses on it using `tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()` I get content and send it to the server. I also use my own bbcode plugin to convert content from html to bbcode before saving. But the problem is when user uses some Accented Characters like `ö,ä,ü` `tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()` transforms it to `&ouml;,&auml;,&uuml;`.
I tried to use `tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'})` but in this case bbcode is not working. It means from

- Wir müssen uns treffen

we have 
<ul><li>Wir müssen uns treffen</li></ul>

But i want to get it with bbcode 
[ * ]Wir müssen uns treffen[ /* ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you will have to employ a conversion function on the server side then that will replace `&ouml;,&auml;,&uuml;` etc... with their real character.

Comment: Is there such one-line function in JavaScript to do it? What I found is only functions written manually...

Comment: Probably becasue of the fact that most Standards originate from the US and they don't use umlauts for example there is no on-liner or other standard functionality. You will have to stick with one of those :(

Comment: okay, then I will try to encode it on server side... and I think in php there is no one-line function as well... can you advice anything?

Comment: so there are functions to encode it html_entity_decode(CHtml::decode($text)); in YII framework it is possible to do in this way

Comment: actually, just now, we found a very good tinymce feature like entity_encoding : 'raw', which fixes this problem on the client side, anyway, thank you Thariama for quick response.